# My iPhone XR keeps making emergency calls without any interaction from me

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, call

This is really weird: three times within the past week, my iPhone XR has called my mother-in-law via the Emergency Call feature, without any apparent interaction from me.

Each time this has happened, the phone has been in my pocket. When I realize that it's calling (because I can faintly hear the phone ringing over the internal speaker), I've taken it out of my pocket and it's on an "Emergency Call" screen (white background with red text) and is dialing my mother-in-law's number.

I do have my mother-in-law listed as an emergency contact in my iPhone's Medical ID, but my mother and wife are also listed there as emergency contacts, and it's never called either of them.

I don't know of any way to dial an emergency contact other than to press and hold the side and volume buttons, then choose Medical ID, then scroll down and tap an emergency contact. I can't possibly be doing that by accident while the phone is in my pocket, so I have no idea how this is getting triggered.

Is it possible Siri is mishearing something and thinking I want to make an emergency call? (I do have "Hey Siri" turned on).

Any ideas? And how do I get it to stop?

Comment: Thats interesting... it might be Siri... apparently Siri can make emergency calls.  It is unlikely that Siri is hearing the same mistake three times in a week though.

Comment: Do you have auto call at pressing power button 3 times on ? Check in Settings -> emergency and SOS